# how to get methods via has_one and belongs_to assocation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rspec, belongs-to, has-one

I have few weeks experience or close to a month learning on Ruby on Rails.  I hope to understand why I can't get methods via associated objects.

I am attempting to get associated objects attached to user instead of stane alone Profile.new e.g. profile with its methods as seen just below.

user.profile.create

user.profile.create!

user.profile.build

instead i get RSpec error messages. NoMethodError:undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

Thanks kindly in advance

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email
  has_one :profile

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

.

```
    # == Schema Information
    #
    # Table name: profiles
    #
    #  id         :integer         not null, primary key
    #  given_name :string(255)
    #  surname    :string(255)
    #  user_id    :integer
    #  created_at :datetime        not null
    #  updated_at :datetime        not null
    #

    class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :given_name, :surname #, :user_id
      belongs_to :user

      validates :user_id, presence: true
    end
```

.

```
    smileymike@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/bffmApp$ bundle exec guard
    Guard uses Libnotify to send notifications.
    Guard is now watching at '/home/smileymike/rails_projects/bffmApp'
    Starting Spork for RSpec
    Using RSpec
    Preloading Rails environment
    Loading Spork.prefork block...
    Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
    Spork server for RSpec successfully started
    Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
    Running all specs
    Running tests with args ["--drb", "-f", "progress", "-r", "/home/smileymike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-rspec-0.7.2/lib/guard/rspec/formatters/notification_rspec.rb", "-f", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter::NotificationRSpec", "--out", "/dev/null", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "spec"]...
    ......FFFFFFFF...............

    Failures:

      1) Profile 
         Failure/Error: before { @profile = user.profile.build(given_name: "Michael", surname: "Colin") }
         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
         # ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      2) Profile 
         Failure/Error: before { @profile = user.profile.build(given_name: "Michael", surname: "Colin") }
         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
         # ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      3) Profile 
         Failure/Error: before { @profile = user.profile.build(given_name: "Michael", surname: "Colin") }
         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
         # ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      4) Profile 
         Failure/Error: before { @profile = user.profile.build(given_name: "Michael", surname: "Colin") }
         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
         # ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      5) Profile 
         Failure/Error: before { @profile = user.profile.build(given_name: "Michael", surname: "Colin") }
         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
         # ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      6) Profile user 
         Failure/Error: before { @profile = user.profile.build(given_name: "Michael", surname: "Colin") }
         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
         # ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      7) Profile when user_id is not present 
         Failure/Error: before { @profile = user.profile.build(given_name: "Michael", surname: "Colin") }
         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
         # ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      8) Profile accessible attributes should not allow access to user_id
         Failure/Error: before { @profile = user.profile.build(given_name: "Michael", surname: "Colin") }
         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
         # ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

    Finished in 1.56 seconds
    29 examples, 8 failures

    Failed examples:

    rspec ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:27 # Profile 
    rspec ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:28 # Profile 
    rspec ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:29 # Profile 
    rspec ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:30 # Profile 
    rspec ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:33 # Profile 
    rspec ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:31 # Profile user 
    rspec ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:37 # Profile when user_id is not present 
    rspec ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:41 # Profile accessible attributes should not allow access to user_id
    Done.

    >
```

.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Profile do

#  before do
    # This code is wrong but it works
#    @profile = Profile.new(given_name: "Michael", surname: "Colin", user_id: user.id)
#  end
#  but I am attempting to create a profile via User/Profile assoications
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { @profile = user.profile.build(given_name: "Michael", surname: "Colin") }

  subject { @profile }

  it { should respond_to(:given_name) }
  it { should respond_to(:surname) }
  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:user) }
  its(:user) { should == user }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when user_id is not present" do
    before { @profile.user_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "accessible attributes" do
    it "should not allow access to user_id" do
      expect do
        Profile.new(user_id: user_id)
      end.should raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end    
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

has_one will give you a build_profile method on user. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference for more details.

The reason you can't do user.profile.build is that there is no profile, so user.build returns nil and it doesn't make sense to ask nil to build a profile. This is different to the has_many case, where out always returns a collection of things - even when the collection is empty - and you can ask the collection to make another member. It's easy to imagine the has_one accessor returning a non-nil "I'm not here" value, which would enable your scenario, but would have other issues (mainly that such a value would not be falsey, leading to arguably less rubyesque code)

Comment: user.build_profile(given_name: "Michael", surname: "Colin")  is the answer.  Bonus, the web link to guides.rubyonrails.org is a bonus is exactly what I am looking for.  Books and online tutorials insufficiently provided these info.

Comment: this is a great reference provided by guides.rubyonrails that i often find myself coming back to time and again